# chromaprint fingerprint of FLAC and MP3

Tags: go, cgo

I would like to create an acoustic fingerprint of a FLAC or MP3 file using the [chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) library in Go. I've been playing around with the following two Go libraries:

- [gochroma](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-fingerprint/gochroma), Go bindings for chromaprint
- [fingerprint](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-fingerprint/fingerprint)

Using the following code, a fingerprint of a "raw audio data stream" can be created (where `reader` is of type `io.Reader`):

```
fpcalc := gochroma.New(gochroma.AlgorithmDefault)
defer fpcalc.Close()

fprint, err := fpcalc.Fingerprint(
        fingerprint.RawInfo{
                Src:        reader,
                Channels:   2,
                Rate:       44100,  
                MaxSeconds: 120,
        }       
)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out what "raw audio data stream" exactly means (my guess: WAVE LPCM streams), but I understand that I can't simply open a FLAC or MP3 file using `os.Open` and pass the stream to `fingerprint.RawInfo.Src`. There are some [examples](https://github.com/go-fingerprint/fingerprint-examples), but these work with files ending in `.raw`.

How can I convert a FLAC (or, secondary, MP3) file/stream to a raw audio data stream in Go? My guess is to use a Go FLAC library like [go-flac](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-flac/go-flac), but I'm not sure where to start. Any hints are welcome!

**EDIT**

Via [go-flac](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-flac/go-flac)'s `GetStreamInfo` it should be possible to access a FLAC file's raw audio data, which can then be passed to `fingerprint.RawInfo.Src` using a reader (I really dislike the fact that [go-flac](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-flac/go-flac)'s `GetStreamInfo` doesn't return an `io.Reader`; instead it returns `[]byte`, so the entire stream is loaded into memory before further processing can actually happen).

Using the following code, a FLAC file's fingerprint can be calculated (basically what `fpcalc` does):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-fingerprint/fingerprint"
    "github.com/go-fingerprint/gochroma"
    "github.com/go-flac/go-flac"
)

func main() {
    f, err := flac.ParseFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    si, err := f.GetStreamInfo()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fpcalc := gochroma.New(gochroma.AlgorithmDefault)
    defer fpcalc.Close()

    fprint, err := fpcalc.Fingerprint(
        fingerprint.RawInfo{
            Src:        bytes.NewReader(f.Frames),
            Channels:   uint(si.ChannelCount),
            Rate:       uint(si.SampleRate),
            MaxSeconds: 120,
        },
    )

    fmt.Println(fprint)
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not return the same fingerprint as `fpcalc` does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `go-flac` isn't a *decoder*, it's just a parser. `Frames` is giving you FLAC frames, not decoded audio.

Comment: well, I am bowing out of this. To anyone that wants to try at this, be warned its a CGO package https://github.com/go-fingerprint/gochroma/blob/master/chromaprint/chromaprint.go You might try this instead though https://github.com/eaburns/flac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following code which decodes a FLAC file to raw audio data using [github.com/eaburns/flac](https://github.com/eaburns/flac) (as Steven Penny pointed out) and then passes the data over to [fingerprint](https://github.com/go-fingerprint/fingerprint)/[gochroma](https://github.com/go-fingerprint/gochroma).

The resulting fingerprint doesn't seem to be the same as the one reported by `fpcalc` for the same FLAC file, but when querying the AcoustID database using the generated fingerprint, the result is correct.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/eaburns/flac"
    "github.com/go-fingerprint/fingerprint"
    "github.com/go-fingerprint/gochroma"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        log.Fatalf("usage: go run fpcalc.go FILE")
    }

    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("os.Open(%s): %s", os.Args[1], err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    d, metadata, err := flac.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("flac.Decode: %s", err)
    }

    fpcalc := gochroma.New(gochroma.AlgorithmDefault)
    defer fpcalc.Close()

    fprint, err := fpcalc.Fingerprint(
        fingerprint.RawInfo{
            Src:        bytes.NewBuffer(d),
            Channels:   uint(metadata.NChannels),
            Rate:       uint(metadata.SampleRate),
            MaxSeconds: 120,
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fpcalc.Fingerprint: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(fprint)
}
```